# Dell Gateway 5000 with Ubuntu Core 16 doesn't identify sim card inserted in the slot

Tags: dell, ubuntu-core, gateway

I have Dell Gateway 5000 with Ubuntu Core 16 installed in it. I am inserting a sim card in the slot, but the Gateway doesn't identify it. The led indicating the mobile network is off. The sim card is working fine with other devices. I want to make Gateway as access point using the sim card network.

Can anyone help me with what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The only thing I did, was to disconnect the cable power, and then connect it again.

I tried sudo power off, sudo reboot, pushing the button, but nothing worked, until I unplugged the cable.

I know it seems be some dumb, but it worked for me.